# Spring 4 - @Scheduled working but @Async not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I have a rest service that is supposed to validate some stuff and call an @Async method on another service. Just like this:

```
@RestController
public class MyRest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/do-stuff", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> doStuff() {
        myService.computeAndDoStuff();
        return "ok thanks";
    }
}

@Service
public class MyService {
    @Scheduled(cron="*/5 * * * * ?")
    public void doSchedule() {
        System.out.println("I like to work");
    }

    @Async
    public void computeAndDoStuff() {
         if (1 < 2) {
             throw new RuntimeException("Indeed");
         }
         System.out.println("I hope it doesn't get printed");
    }
}
```

Even though MyService keep working and printing "I like to work" every 5 seconds, when the rest is hit at "/rest/do-stuff", it returns a 500 http code with the stacktrace and the "Indeed" message.

Well, since I called from another class (no proxy class problem here), I was hoping my rest would return a 200 http code with an "ok thanks" message. What am I missing?

Just in case, my dispatcher-servlet.xml looks like this:

```
...
    <task:scheduler id="scheduleExec" pool-size="10" />
    <task:executor id="asynExec" pool-size="10" />
    <task:annotation-driven executor="asynExec" scheduler="scheduleExec" proxy-target-class="true" />
...
```

By the way, if I comment this three lines above, @Scheduled stops working (but no @Async working of course :P).

Comment: Set a breakpoint on method entry and see what threads it and the request handler are running on.

Comment: are you getting the 500 http and Indeed? if so, why is it unexpected? your code for `computeAndDoStuff()` does just that, i.e, `throw new RuntimeException("Indeed");`

Comment: @yarivt yes, my code for `computeAndDoStuff()` does that, but it does that in a @Async method. The rest service, as far as I understand, should be calling `computeAndDoStuff()` and then return "ok thanks" right away. Without waiting for `computeAndDoStuff()` to do anything...

Comment: @Bruno it just means the code runs on a different thread. try to add `sleep(5000)` at the start of the compute method and see if you get the "ok thanks" back (you need to return the correct object and not string though). also, run the debugger and see what happens

Comment: Well, I have manage to solve it, there was a conflict between my dispatcher-servlet.xml and applicationContext.xml (duplicate config). After fixing it my rest service started to return 200 http code, as I expected, even though there was an exception thrown in my @Async method.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using your example and it works, even XML based configuration. On call to the rest endpoint, I get a response saying `ok thanks` (Although it gave me a compile time error earlier as my return type wasn't String and I was trying to return one).

Comment: Well, I gave it a try, even though there are no difference between your config and mine (just the order, but if that matter would affect the @Scheduled as well), and it didn't work.

Comment: @Bruno Yeah I didn't think about that. Check out the edit to the post, I still believe the problem is XML config.

Comment: thanks for your help, I have manage to verify that there was a conflict between dispatcher-servelt.xml and applicationContext.xml (duplicate config) that was messing things up.